Can i stop my dog from attacking other dog
My dog keeps attacking my other dog. It killed a rabbit. Immediately turned on other dog. I have to keep them separated. Each chance it gets it for after the other dog. They use to be able to be together with no fighting. Can this behavior go away?

In most cases of dog aggression, educating the pet parent has the highest chance of success. So I agree that your question is answered in the link that Allison C provided. Hire a professional dog trainer who visits you at home, analyzes your dogs' behavior and teaches you how to avoid this kind of aggression.
